# Refactoring method containing LINQ queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, refactoring

I'm having a little trouble deciding the best way to refactor a method which contains LINQ queries which are very similar but not identical.

Consider a method which is something along these lines:

```
public SomeObject GetTheObject(IMyObject genericObject) {
    Type t = genericObject.GetType();
    SomeObject so = null;

    switch(t.Name) {
        case "Type1":
            var object1 = (from o in object1s where o.object1id == genericObject.id).FirstOrDefault();
            so = (SomeObject)object1;
        break;
        case "Type2":
            var object2 = (from o in object2s where o.object2id == genericObject.id).FirstOrDefault();
            so = (SomeObject)object2;
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }

    return so;
}
```

This is just an illustration, but imagine I'm needing to execute a different query (different in that it uses a different ObjectSet, uses slightly different fields (object1id vs object2id) and returns a different type.
Other than that, the queries are the same.

Is there a sensible way to refactor this kind of method? It feels like I've missed something obvious. Perhaps I have to use the exact method and I can't avoid re-writing the query, it just seems like I SHOULD be able to somehow!

Any pointers greatly appreciated

Comment: I tried it with Reflection, but couldn't get past the LINQ statement ("from o in object1s where o.object1id"). You should look into dynamically generating a LINQ statement.

Comment: Hi Graham, this would certainly be an option except for the fact that I'm trying to keep the DAL encapsulated in a Repository<T> which leaves me restricted in the methods I can use to dynamically build a query. I tried to build a factory to return the concrete Repository instance I wanted. But this left me in a similar situation as I described to Paolo, namely that because my Repository requires a concrete EntityObject type, that I cannot create one based around an interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have just oversimplified your scenario, but the smelly part of your function is the cast to SomeObject. Couldn't you just work with interfaces and (if needed) cast the result at the call site? You could have your Type1 and Type2 implement a common interface where id1 and id2 are exposed as id, for example (or decorate them if you don't control Type1 and Type2)

I.e.

```
public static IMyObject GetTheObject(List<IMyObject> theList,  int id)
{
    var ret = (from o in theList
        where o.id==id
        select o).FirstOrDefault();

    return ret;
}
```

For instance, if you have:

```
    public interface IMyObject {int id {get;}}

    public class Foo : IMyObject {public int id {get; set;}}
    public class Bar : IMyObject {public int id {get; set;}}
```

you can do:

```
var l1 = new List<IMyObject>(){new Foo(){id=1}, new Foo(){id=2}};
var l2 = new List<IMyObject>(){new Bar(){id=1}, new Bar(){id=2}};   

var obj1 = Test.GetTheObject(l1, 1);
var obj2 = Test.GetTheObject(l2, 2);
```

And cast the objects after you call the function, if you have to.

EDIT:
if you're stuck with concrete objects and casts, the best refactoring I could come up with is:

```
public static SomeObject GetTheObject(IMyObject genericObject) {
    Type t = genericObject.GetType();

    Func<SomeObject, bool> WhereClause = null;
    IEnumerable<SomeObject> objs = null; // IEnumerable<T> is covariant, 
                      // so we can assign it both an IEnumerable<object1>
                      // and an IEnumerable<object2> (provided object1 and 2 are
                      // subclasses of SomeObject)

    switch(t.Name) {
        case "Type1":
            WhereClause = o => ((Object1)o).object1id == genericObject.id;      
            objs = object1s;
        break;
        case "Type2":
            WhereClause = o =>  ((Object2)o).object2id == genericObject.id;     
            objs = object2s;
        break;
    }

    var ob = objs
    .Where(WhereClause)
    .FirstOrDefault();

    return (SomeObject)ob;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think I did simplify things a bit, the issue I'd have with working with interfaces is that my query is actually a query on a  generic repository which requires a concrete type. This means I can't do Respository<IMyObject> at the moment which is causing me grief.
I could I suppose write another repository where T: IMyObject, rather than the T:EntityObject it is at the moment, but that feels like overkill, it may however be needed.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald: the refactoring I could come up with does not look like much of an improvement over yours, but at least it reduces the duplication in linq code... :)

Comment: thanks for that, I will have a play when I get a chance on Thursday, I was hoping to get away from the switching logic as in my real life situation I might have 10-12 options and I'd rather no bung up the screen with case statements! then again it might be the only option!